# No cuspidal character sheaves on GL(n)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

We need a reference for the fact that there are no cuspidal character sheaves on $GL_n$ unless $n=1$.

See page 11 of http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~arakawa/Henderson_mgsctalk2.pdf.

Comment: You can cite 17.12 and 17.13 of Lusztig's "Character Sheaves IV". From this it follows from the fact that the symmetric group has no Cuspidal two-sided cells.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a question of character sheaves in that slides but cuspidal pair as it is defined in Lusztig "Intersection cohomology complexes on a reductive group".

As it is explained in the slides, there is no cuspidal pair for $GL_n$ because for this group the generalized Springer correspondence is just the ordinary Springer correspondence, i.e. is obtained from the cuspidal triple $(T,\{1\},\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})$, where $T$ is a maximal torus of $GL_n$.